# Laravel 5.3 Auth::attempt() always returns false

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.3

When a new user get registered then it automatically logins, Which is working fine. I am hashing the password like this :

```
'$newUser->password = bcrypt($request->get('password'));'
```

It successfully hashes the password, My users table have password column which is varchar 255. And i have remember_token field too in users table. `'dd($request->all())'` returns:

```
array:3 [
  "email" => "info@hotmail.com"
  "_token" => "QIwnHacApWg3SotAXtoCCMFNK3FYFoFBAv2LSx4c"
  "password" => "adminadmin"
]
```

And, The email and password is 100% correct against the users table record.
The request is Ajax so i have the following code of JS:

```
$('.post-btn').click(function(){            
    $.ajax({
        url: '/sign-in',
        type: "post",
        data: {'email':$('input[name=email]').val(), '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),'password': $('input[name=password]').val()},
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            window.location = '/';
        }
    });      
});
```

**The authenticate method** :

```
public function authenticate(Request $request) {
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),
        [
            'email' => "required",
            'password' => 'required'   
        ]
    );

    $user = array('email' => $request->get('email'),'password' => $request->get('password'));
        if (Auth::attempt($user)) {
            $response = array(
                'status' => 'success',
                'msg' => 'Successfully Logins.',
            );
            $user = new \App\User;
            if(Auth::check()) {

            }
            return \Response::json($response);
        } else {
            $response = array(
                'status' => 'failed',
                'msg' => 'Invalid Credentials!',
            );
            return \Response::json($response);
        }
    }
```

**The input field names are correct.**

What else I am missing ?

Comment: why not use `Hash::make` to hash the password, that is laravel default one.

Comment: It doesn't look like the hashing works when you're registering your account. Laravel hashes your input when you try to login and compares the hash to what is in your database. The hash is not the same as "adminadmin", so it fails.

Comment: @jycr753 Let me try

Comment: Your ajax request is sending `HTTP POST`.  `$request->get('email');` is for `HTTP GET`. Use `$request->input('email');` instead.

Comment: use `$request->email` or `$request->input('email')` instead of `$request->get('email')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This work for me:

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),
        [
            'email' => "required",
            'password' => 'required'

        ]
    );
    $email = $request->input('email');
    $password = $request->input('password');
    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
        // Authentication passed...
        return \Response::json([
            'status' => 'success',
            'msg' => 'Successfully Logins.',
        ]);
    }
    else {
        return \Response::json([
            'status' => 'failed',
            'msg' => 'Invalid Credentials!',
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you..

```
$user = array('email' => $request->email,'password' => $request->password);
```